# Как изменить прилетевший по ajax html перед вставкой в документ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В переменной строка (html код) как преобразовать ее содержимое а затем вставить в документ?

Ниже привел пример кода, как я пробовал это сделать

```js
var html = '<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>';
$(html).find('li').each(function(i, li) {
  $(html).find('li').eq(i).text('Какой то текст');
});
$('body').append(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var html = '<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>';
var $html = $(html);
$html.find('li').each((i, el) => $(el).text('Какой-то текст - ' + i + ", old: " + $(el).text()));
$('body').append($html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Зря вы стрелочные функции добавили)) хорошо скопировать успел))

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Переделывание стрелочной функции на традиционную, если в ней не используется `this` и т.п., - тривиально.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, если не используешь таскер/сборщик, то преобразовать современный JS-код в старый и унылый, можно на странице https://babeljs.io/repl :)